# An example of a FlagsAttribute enum in the Base Class Library?

Tags: .net, .net-core, enums

Is there an example of an enum that is decorated with [FlagsAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute) in the Base Class Library? Preferably something easy to explain, not too obscure, perhaps in the System namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Here are few good ones:

- [System.ConsoleModifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolemodifiers)
- [System.StringSplitOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions)
- [System.AttributeTargets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attributetargets)
- [System.IO.FileAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileaccess)

I could not find this by searching the web. I wrote this script:

```
open System
open System.Reflection

let isPublicFlagsEnum (t: Type) =
    t.IsEnum && 
    t.IsPublic &&
    not(isNull(t.GetCustomAttribute(typeof<FlagsAttribute>)))

typeof<String>.Assembly.GetTypes()
|> Seq.where(isPublicFlagsEnum)
|> Seq.map(fun t -> t.FullName)
|> Seq.sort
|> Seq.iter(printfn "%s")
```